# Heron TumblingWindowBolt based on count not seconds

Tags: python, heron

Heron documentation says that it is possible to implement Tumbling windows based on counts. However, heronpy.api.bolt.window_bolt.TumblingWindowBolt has only WINDOW_DURATION_SECS field. How can I implement TumblingWindowBolt based on tuple counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Python API hasn't implemented the feature yet. Java has the best feature support if it is an option to you.